# Verifying Active Directory Federation Services(ADFS) installation

Tags: active-directory, adfs, adfs2.0

Active Directory Federation Service has been installed on Windows Server 2012 along with Active Directory.

When I try to execute https:/{server-name}/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml or https:/{server-name}/adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon.htm my internet explorer shows me host not resolvable.

I can ping the DNS server and the service seems to be running fine. No Certification errors exist. I can see entry of /adfs/ls in ADFS console endpoint tab.

What could be the reason for getting a host not resolvable error? And how can I go about fixing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue. I needed to disable proxy in the network options.